# Is there a way to convert Html to String without highlighting hyperlinks?

Tags: android, html, string

I know that I can use the default `Html.fromHtml(string)` but it highlights links by default. Is there a way to prevent that behavior?

P.S.

I'm trying to feed it straight to `TextView` using `.setText()` without saving it to `String`. I want to keep all the formatting except links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need text you can fetch it with:

```
String string = Html.fromHtml(string).toString();
```

**Edit:**

Since you want to remove only the links, you can use `String.replaceAll` before parsing the html:

```
// Remove <a href*>
html = html.replaceAll("<a href.*?>", "");
// Remove </a>
html = html.replaceAll("</a>", "");
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried that, but I want other formatting (like bold text etc). `toString` removes that